# Warning: db2_fetch_assoc(): Fetch Failure

Tags: php, linux, db2, odbc

This is probably very simple (I'm a novice), but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I'm using Linux, DB2 and PHP.
My simple DB2 query from PHP only returns rows with integer values, but fails with "Fetch Failure" for anything else (varchar ...).

The query works with db2cli for all values:

echo "select COLUMN from TEST.TABLE"" | ./db2cli execsql -dsn SCHEMA

But fails in PHP:

```
$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=$database;" . 

"HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$passwd;";
$conn = db2_pconnect($conn_string, '', '');
if ($conn) {
        $sql = 'select COLUMN from TEST.TABLE';
        $options = array('cursor' => DB2_SCROLLABLE, 'binmode' => DB2_BINARY);
        $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql, $options);
        if ($stmt) {
                $result = db2_execute($stmt);
                if (!$result) {
                        echo "exec errormsg: " .db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt);
                }
                $total_rows = db2_num_rows($stmt);
                        print "<br>Total rows: $total_rows";
                for ($i = 0; $i < $total_rows; $i++) {
                        $row = db2_fetch_array($stmt);
                        print "<br>$row[0]";
                }
        } else {
                echo "exec erromsg: " . db2_stmt_erromsg($stmt);
        }
        db2_close($conn);
        } else {
                echo "failed #2 ".db2_conn_errormsg();
        }



}
```

It will display any rows with integer values, but empty strings for everything else with the error "Fetch Failure" in the log. I tried db2_fetch_array, db2_fetch_assoc and db2_fetch_both.

Note: I've added the superfluous stuff like db2_scrollable and db2_num_rows later on in attempts to solve the problem. Unsuccessfully.

**EDIT: I can even FILTER by the values that won't display ( SELECT column WHERE column = 'value') and it'll return the correct number of rows.**

Comment: Where is your code failing?  What's the error message it returns – please provide the full error message you're seeing, not just "Warning: db2_fetch_assoc(): Fetch Failure"

Comment: That is the full message. The rest is just the path and line in the file. Here it is anyway: "Warning: db2_fetch_array(): Fetch Failure in /var/www/html/test3.php on line 53 " NOTE: Error reporting is set to E_ALL | E_STRICT. This only occurs when fetching non-integer values from the database.